# How to deal with long ggplot2 title?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

[image]I am building an R shiny App which is supposed to load a certain confidential data for my company and then load some settings that are provided in separate Excel files in form of tables with columns every column can contain more than filled cell or nothing .Based on these values that data will be automatically filtered and based on that filtered data PowerPoint slide will be generated .The generated slide will have that settings as Titel but since some times the values(strings) provided in those cells are long than the concatenated final Titel will be too long and exceeds the slide´s frame and will not be seen. Can anybody help me here since i tried many tricks?
#action button for generating the slides based on the settings files and saving them in Reports_FCM folder.

```
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    newdata<-list()
    req(input$dateRangeFCM)
    files<-list.files(paste0("/YE/YieldReport/05 Projekte/R_Shiny/FCM-FRM-Reporting/YieldReport/Settings_FCM","/",input$FCM),pattern=".xlsx")
    for (i in 1:length(files)){
      newdata[[i]]<-readxl::read_excel(paste0("/YE/YieldReport/05 Projekte/R_Shiny/FCM-FRM-Reporting/YieldReport/Settings_FCM","/",input$FCM,"/",files[i]))
    }
    for ( j in 1:length(files)){
      df<- FCM_mergeddata()
      data<-df[df$M_Datum >=input$dateRangeFCM[1] & df$M_Datum <= input$dateRangeFCM[2],]
      for(f in names(newdata[[j]])){
        if(!is.na(newdata[[j]][[f]])){
          data <-data[data[[f]] %in% newdata[[j]][[f]],]
        }
        
      }
      data[,c("M_Datum")]<-as.Date(format(as.Date(data[,c("M_Datum")]), "%Y-%m-01"))
      req(data$M_Datum,data$Yield)
      new_data<-data.frame("M_Datum"=data$M_Datum,"Yield"=data$Yield)
      req(new_data$M_Datum,new_data$Yield)
      Agg_data1<-aggregate(Yield~M_Datum,new_data,mean)
      req(Agg_data1$M_Datum,Agg_data1$Yield)
      newAgg_data1<-data.frame("M_Datum"=Agg_data1$M_Datum,"Yield"=Agg_data1$Yield)
      hline_data <- data.frame(y = c(mean(newAgg_data1$Yield)-sd(newAgg_data1$Yield),mean(newAgg_data1$Yield), mean(newAgg_data1$Yield)+sd(newAgg_data1$Yield)), type = factor(c(2, 1, 2)), 
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      if(input$horizontal_lines == TRUE){
        Mean_yield_plot1<-ggplot(newAgg_data1, aes(x=factor(format(M_Datum, "%b %Y"), levels=format(sort(unique(M_Datum)),"%b %Y")), y=Yield,group = 1)) +
          geom_point(size=7,colour="#007A9D",shape=4) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1,face="bold"))+
          theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "top", legend.key = element_blank(), 
                legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
                axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                axis.title.y.left  = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                plot.title = element_text(color="#007A9D",size=24, face='bold')
          )+
          ylab("Mean Yield")+
          xlab("")+
          ggtitle(paste0("FCM-Yield Trend :","  ",paste0(c(na.omit(newdata[[j]][[5]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[6]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[1]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[2]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[3]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[4]])),collapse = "\n" )))+
          ylim(newscaleFCM())+
          geom_hline(data = hline_data, 
                     aes(yintercept = y, linetype = type, colour = type)) +
          scale_colour_manual(values = c("#007A9D", "#EF783D"), 
                              labels = c("Mean", "Mean+-sd"),
                              name = "Key:") +
          scale_linetype_manual(values = 1:2, 
                                labels = c("Mean", "Mean+-sd"),
                                name = "Key:")
      } else {
        
        Mean_yield_plot1<-ggplot(newAgg_data1, aes(x=factor(format(M_Datum, "%b %Y"), levels=format(sort(unique(M_Datum)),"%b %Y")), y=Yield,group = 1)) +
          geom_point(size=7,colour="#007A9D",shape=4) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1,face="bold"))+
          theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "top", legend.key = element_blank(), 
                legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"),
                axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                axis.title.y.left  = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
                plot.title = element_text(color="#007A9D",size=24, face='bold')
          )+
          ylab("Mean Yield")+
          xlab("")+
          ggtitle(paste0("FCM-Yield Trend :","  ",paste0(c(na.omit(newdata[[j]][[5]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[6]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[1]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[2]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[3]]),na.omit(newdata[[j]][[4]])),collapse = "/")))+
          ylim(newscaleFCM())
        
      }
      Agg_data2=aggregate(Yield ~ M_Datum,new_data,length) 
      req(Agg_data2$M_Datum,Agg_data2$Yield)
      newAgg_data2<-data.frame("M_Datum"=Agg_data2$M_Datum,"Yield"=Agg_data2$Yield)
      if(input$link_lines == TRUE){
        Wafer_qty_plot1<-ggplot(newAgg_data2, aes(x=factor(format(M_Datum, "%b %Y"), levels=format(sort(unique(M_Datum)),"%b %Y")), y=Yield,group = 1)) + 
          geom_point(size=7,colour="#EF783D",shape=17) +
          geom_line(color="#EF783D")+
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1,face="bold"))+
          theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#EF783D"),
                axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "#EF783D"))+
          ylab("Wafer Quantity")+
          xlab("")
      } else {
        Wafer_qty_plot1<-ggplot(newAgg_data2, aes(x=factor(format(M_Datum, "%b %Y"), levels=format(sort(unique(M_Datum)),"%b %Y")), y=Yield,group = 1)) + 
          geom_point(size=7,colour="#EF783D",shape=17) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1,face="bold"))+
          theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#EF783D"),
                axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "#EF783D"))+
          ylab("Wafer Quantity")+
          xlab("")
      }
      Agg_data3<-aggregate(Yield ~ M_Datum, new_data, sd) 
      req(Agg_data1$M_Datum,Agg_data1$Yield,Agg_data2$Yield,Agg_data3$Yield)
      stat_data<-data.frame(format(Agg_data1$M_Datum,"%b %Y"),round(Agg_data1$Yield,digits=1),round(Agg_data3$Yield,digits=1),Agg_data2$Yield)
      colnames(stat_data)<-c("Months","Mean","SD","Wafer Qty")
      stat_table_plot1<-tableGrob(t(stat_data))
      th<- sum(stat_table_plot1$heights)
      plots <- arrangeGrob(Mean_yield_plot1,Wafer_qty_plot1,nrow=2)
      FCM_final_plot=grid.arrange(plots,stat_table_plot1, heights = unit.c(unit(1, "null"),th))
      save_place <- file.path(paste0("/YE/transfer/Reports_FCM/",res_auth[["user"]],j,".svg"))
      ggsave(save_place,FCM_final_plot, width=54, height=34,dpi= 300,units="cm",limitsize = F)
    }
  }
  )
```

The code begins with reading the excel files and saving then in a certain data (list) and then use that list for filtration.The rest is not the important except the code where ggtitle() where you should focus because a right change of code out there will solve the problem.I provide also a slide where the Titel exceeds the page.

Comment: Why do the setting need to be in the title? I would consider putting the settings as text below (or above) the plot, possibly by combining the ggplot with a [textGrob](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grid/versions/3.6.2/topics/grid.text) using `gridExtra::grid.arrange`.

Comment: @Roland i forgot to add the plot .Now you can see it . I do not know if that text or Titel is .Anyway if you have a the code for your solution then please provide it to me.The text should or Titel should be always above and not inside the plot.

Comment: `base::strwrap` / `stringr::str_wrap`? `library(ggtext)` + `theme(plot.title = element_textbox_simple()`?

Comment: "The rest is not the important" suggests you should edit your question so it just gets to the important part, and includes fake data so that the code can be run by others.